# Assigning the values to array from jq and iterate over the values using cb commands

Tags: bash, shell, jq, couchbase

I have the below json in a file from which I wanted to take the "ids" from all price object and put into an array variable.

```json
{
  "documentType": "Prices",
  "fullCharges": [
    {
      "ResourceId": null,
      "price": {
        "href": null,
        "id": "8ddaaabc92bc"
      },
      "product": {
        "href": null,
        "id": "123"
      }
    },
    {
      "price": {
        "href": null,
        "id": "326f0f273258"
      },
      "product": {
        "href": null,
        "id": "123"
      }
    }
  ],
  "createdBy": "test",
  "createdOn": "2021-10-05T00:00:55Z",
  "currentSeqNum": 2
}
```

I am using the below query but the result is coming in the proper way.

`priceIds=$(jq -r .fullCharges[].price.id ${file})`

Using above command, it is behaving like a single value, not like array. If I print the priceId value it is only showing the last value.

`326f0f273258 instead of 8ddaaabc92bc 326f0f273258`

And when I am looping over it, again it is behaving as a single value.

```
for price in "${priceIds[@]}"
do
  printf "$price"
  
  cbq -u Administrator -p Administrator  -e "http://localhost:8093"  --script="select * FROM \`com.src.test.price\` where docId==\"$price\";"
  
done
```

Output command of above loop: `` select * FROM `com.src.test.price` where documentId=="8ddaaabc92bc 326f0f273258"; ``

There should be 2 command like these

```
select * FROM `com.src.test.price` where documentId=="8ddaaabc92bc"
select * FROM `com.src.test.price` where documentId=="326f0f273258"
```

Comment: Shouldn't that assignment be `priceIds=($(...))`? The extra parens actually create an array.

Comment: Yes, extra parens works. However, now it is adding extra line when I am trying to use first value from array. Is there a way to remove extra line from the each value in array inside the loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using extra parens, it helped me to create array.
2. Using the below sed command over array item variable, i was able to remove extra line from it.

`price=$(echo "$price" | sed 's/^[ \n]*//;s/[ \n]*$//')`